# How Import data from a text file in a table created in mysql using java?

Tags: jdbc

I have first read the data from database using File writer function and stored the text file into the database.

Now I want to copy the contents of that text file into a new database created. The text file itself is of 6 mb so the data is quite large. I want to separate fields from that text file and store them in a string and use those strings to transfer the data into new table created. I am confused about the approach.

I know how can I read the data from the text file as I have already done that and I can display same too using Eclipse console. But how to store the same content of text file in a table of mysql database using java?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql, use mysqldump dump tables and use -e option with mysql to import tables.

Parse text file and translate to sql is a bit more complicated.

Comment: i wasnt able to create sql dump in mysql 5.6.19. I tried lots of syntax changes but nothing worked.

Comment: I suggest open a new question about mysqldump :)